# is microsoft exchange and sharepoint the same?

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server, onedrive

There's this time of my life whereby I am confuse with all the Microsoft Technologies that exists.

Can anyone help clarify the difference between MS Exchange and the MS Sharepoint and the MS Onedrive for business, that was formerly Skydrive Pro?

Answer (score 1):

The big points:

- MS Exchange is email, contacts, calendaring.  ActiveSync is the mobile component of these services.
- SharePoint, at it's most basic level, is a "Team Site" platform.  People will do MANY different things on Sharepoint.
- OneDrive for Business is a "dropbox" service that actually runs on SharePoint technologies.  Many features from SharePoint are taken out of ODFB, such that it is really just a Document Library.

Confusion often comes from mail integration into SharePoint.  SharePoint is capable of hosting email integrated services, as well as calendaring.  Some of these functions will tie into Exchange, and some will not.  For instance, a SharePoint calendar is not an Exchange object, but it can be connected to Outlook.

If you have any particular points of confusion, please clarify your question.